# Consume old kafka messages based on a schedule

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have a use-case where we need to consume messages from Kafka topic which are at least one hour old, every five minutes.
Is it possible using kafka?

Comment: I think you need to reset the consumer group offset to the time/duration you want

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Kafka client, you can programmatically use an `offsets_for_time` function call, then pass that information into `seek` method of a consumer instance before you poll.

You can also do the same with `kafka-consumer-groups --reset-offsets` CLI.

However, constantly seeking a consumer might not be the best pattern; perhaps dumping into a database or filesystem might be more optimal, based on your query patterns.